# Using curl with cookies (username / password)

Tags: php, bash, curl, cookies, wget

I hope someone can help me out on this one.
I have been trying this for a while now, with all sorts of variations and cannot seem to get this to work.

I am trying to script a way to log in to https://login.three.ie/ to check account balance from */My_account_balance

I have tried all sorts of wget commands but from what I read, curl is more likely able to accomplish this task..

I have been trying variations I came across online, including from here on stackoverflow but nothing seems to work.

Here is the last one I tried:

```
    curl -X POST -c cookies.txt -u "Uern@me:P@ssw0rd" https://login.three.ie/
```

This does save the cookies file here:

```
    $ cat cookies.txt

    Netscape HTTP Cookie File

    #http://curl.haxx.se/docs/http-cookies.html
    This file was generated by libcurl! Edit at your own risk.
    HttpOnly_login.three.ie        FALSE   /       FALSE   1433988274
    laravel_session eyJpdiI6IkFZWmxvZ2oyXC9NNGVIbHVpejZwRWp3PT0iLCJ2YWx1ZSI6Imxkd25UKzBoMldiQlhYZVJnVUpuNUVsblZ1cGJYZWcwM2E1bTtIWHRiQ2pwV0VwemJ4NFlYcDlzTndSeFRNanpwdDhMMTIrS2RGZGdGd0RNZU1yREJ3PT0iLCJtYWMiOiI0NWUwYzc1TY4ODI3ZmY3ODY5NjliODkxODMyODIzMjQwNmNkNjljNTE2NzQxNmQ4MzhhNDljNTdjM2QwZGY1In0%3D
```

But when I try to re-use the cookie, it looks like there is a redirect or something, as this is what I get:

```
    $ curl -b cookies.txt  https://my3account.three.ie/My_account_balance
    <html><head><title>302 Moved Temporarily</title></head>
    <body bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
    <p>This document you requested has moved temporarily.</p>
    <p>It's now at <a href="https://sso.three.ie/mylogin//login?auth-        
    required=seamless&amp;service=https&#37;3A&#37;F&#37;                   
    2Fmy3account.three.ie&#37;2FMy_account_balance">https://sso.three.ie/mylogin//login?auth-required=seamless&amp;service=https&#37;3A&#37;2F&#37;2Fmy3account.three.ie&#37;2FMy_account_balance</a>.</p>
```

I don't understand what's happening here.
Does anyone have an idea of what's going wrong, or even better, how to remedy this?

Thanks

Comment: There's nothing wrong with 302 Moved Temporarily; it's just a redirection. Use `-L, --location` to follow redirection.

Comment: Thanks, this seems closer, but now I am getting a page where its like its not quite pulling the page I am looking for yet:    <html>    
    <head>
    <title>3 Single Sign On Service</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var test = (function(cookieName) {
            })('three-sso-ROI-COOKIE');
            if (test == null) {
                self.parent.location.href = 'http://my3account.three.ie/Cookie';
            } else {
                self.parent.location.href = 'https://my3account.three.ie/My_account_balance';

Comment: And at the end of the page it has the link I am  requesting:  </head>
    <body class="P00_id">
        <div class="threePortlet P00_id P00_SsoSeamless">
            <p>Login successful.</p>
            <p>Click <a href="https://my3account.three.ie/My_account_balance" target="_parent">here</a> to access the service you requested.</p>
        </div>
    </body>

Comment: It looks like its just the SSO landing page before moving to the correct requested page. The page is mentioned at the end, here:  <p>Login successful.</p> <p>Click <a href="my3account.three.ie/My_account_balance"; target="_parent">here</a> to access the service you requested.</p>   <---- That is the requested page but it isnt fully reaching it.. thanks for the help btw

Comment: Well I never got that login successful message before using the -L parameter.

Comment: So you actually saw a login successful message? Then not sure. I'm on my phone right now, and I might be able to help you have a look later when I get back to my desk, if it's not too much trouble.

Comment: I can't register, so I'm afraid I can't offer any more help.

Comment: I just realized it isn't using the cookie at all. After deleting the cookie file and just running $ curl https://my3account.three.ie/My_account_balance/ -L it shows the "login successful" message so that's just part of the html for when a page is requested without logging in.

Comment: Yes, that's what I expected. Simple auth almost never works. What I would suggest: open your browser's dev tools, navigate to whichever plane that shows you all the HTTP request, and log in from the browser. Note the POST request sent by the browser. Then reproduce it in curl. That's what I typically do when I want to sign on browserlessly.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will add as many fields from the html header I see in the POST request that curl allows (--user-agent) etc, which I am assuming you mean. The Post data part (username / password) is the same except a "section" part (section = section) which I'm not sure if that needs to be added or not, but I will play around with it

Comment: What you need is `--header`. Add the headers. Not sure what you mean by section.

Comment: Right, but in the Request Headers there are values for more than curl allows (I think), such as values for Host, User Agent, Accept, Accept Language, Accept Encoding, Referer, Cookie (taken from the file), Content Type, Content Length etc - I will add as many as I can and see how it goes tomorrow

Comment: As I said, use the --header option, which accepts anything. Read the man page.

Answer (score 0):

You need to comment this line :

```
This file was generated by libcurl! Edit at your own risk.
```

since it's obviously an invalid cookie.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to comment those out in the original post, but they are commented out in the cookies file